# Windows batch breaks off after output redirect / BaseX

Tags: windows, batch-file, basex

I am using a Windows batch file to automatize XQuery requests on the BaseX database. The syntax is the following:

```
..\bin\basex -c "commands1.txt" > ".\result\1.xml"
..\bin\basex -c "commands2.txt" > ".\result\2.xml"
..\bin\basex -c "commands3.txt" > ".\result\3.xml"
```

The "commands1.txt" etc. file contains the actual BaseX commands and works fine. There is a paramter "-o" to specify an output file, but this does not seem to work. The only way I found to catch the XQuery result is to do an output redirect with ">" in the batch file.

The problem: The batch file breaks off execution after the first line, i.e. after writing .\result\1.xml. The next line "commands2.txt" and "commands3.txt" do not get called (even though all of them exist and are in the same folder, and they do get called correctly if the first line of the batch file).

I read everything I could find about the Windows batch output redirect but I couldn't come up with any explanation. The following example works just fine:

```
echo 'hello' > test.txt
echo 'hello1' > test1.txt
```

I would much appreciate input why the BaseX batch file (see first example above) doesn't work?

Comment: is it `..\bin\basex.exe` or `..\bin\basex.bat`?

Comment: `..\bin\basex.bat` -- (There are no .exe or .cmd files in that directoy.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to call a bat file, use `call batfile.bat`. If you just use `batfile.bat`, you transfer control to it. There is no return.

`call` "calls" the batfile and returns.

Comment: Wow! That was fast. Thank you very much! --- I wonder why the output in the cmd does not progress when I run the corrected file. It only shows `call ..\bin\basex.bat -c "test1_ne
u.txt"  1>".\result\test1.xml"` and even though my other xml files get correctly written the console does not show the other lines that get executed.

Comment: I assume, `basex.bat` starts with `@echo OFF` and doesn't care to set it back to ON.

Comment: Yep. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Wikipedia https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Programming_CMD: "Starting with Windows XP, the ECHO ON command is optional. The command interpreter automatically enables it after the BAT file terminates." --- Apparently it doesn't. Windows7 here.

Comment: your secondary BAT file runs within the same context as your primary. so "batch-processing" doesn't terminate, when secondary.bat returns control to primary.bat. (yeah, not very intuitive, but makes sense, when you think about it)